# Different vertical spacing just in header row of table

Tags: tables, spacing

Does anyone know how to make the header row of a table of a different thickness than the body rows? I can control the standard 'thickness' of the rows via: `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}`, where 1.25 is the multiple of standard thickness, but it doesn't seem to have any effect (in fact, throws error) if I try to change this value mid-way through the table construction.

What I was hoping to be able to do, was something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
    \hline
    Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3\\
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \hline
    A & B & C\\
    \hline
    D & E & F\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: On a case-by-case basis, you can insert a "strut". See [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764) with a particular emphasis on "[Alternative padding approaches](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5764)".

Comment: The strut method works perfectly. By adding it to my `\beforeheader{...}` command, get applied on every table. Cheers.